# Get `bs` (splines) equivalent in Python

Tags: python, r, scipy, spline, bspline

In the `r` programming language, the following

```r
require(stats)
require(splines)
knots = quantile(women$height, seq(0.1,0.9,length.out = 5))
bs(women$height, knots=knots, degree=3)
```

returns

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.6284418529    0.323939099 0.024295432 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.2155814707    0.599894720 0.182883868 0.001639942 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.0349854227    0.495626822 0.438289602 0.031098154 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.0001619695    0.245586330 0.620809038 0.133442663 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.072886297 0.584548105 0.338678328 0.003887269 0.000000000 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.009110787 0.384718173 0.561892614 0.044278426 0.000000000 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.166666667 0.666666667 0.166666667 0.000000000 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.044278426 0.561892614 0.384718173 0.009110787 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.003887269 0.338678328 0.584548105 0.072886297 0.0000000000    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.133442663 0.620809038 0.245586330 0.0001619695    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.031098154 0.438289602 0.495626822 0.0349854227    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.001639942 0.182883868 0.599894720 0.2155814707    0.00000000
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.024295432 0.323939099 0.6284418529    0.02332362
0.0000000000    0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.0000000000    1.00000000
```

Is there a Python equivalent? I have tried [BSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html) from `scipy`, but it requires that the coefficients already be known and be passed in.

How can I just generate the B-spline basis matrix, having passed in an array, knots, and degree?

---

To reproduce the input Python, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

women_height = np.array([58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72])
knots = array([59.4, 62.2, 65. , 67.8, 70.6])
```

Comment: `BSpline.design_matrix` will be available in scipy 1.8, when it's released. Meanwhile, you can use scipy master branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turning a comment into an answer, `BSpline.design_matrix` is constructing what you are after, in the csr sparse format. It'll be available from scipy 1.8 when it is released. Until then, you can either grab the master branch of scipy, or use a workaround suggested by the docs (https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.design_matrix.html#scipy.interpolate.BSpline.design_matrix) :

```
t = ... 
c = np.eye(len(t) - k - 1)
design_matrix_gh = BSpline(t, c, k)(x)
```

EDIT: R documentation, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/splines/versions/3.6.2/topics/bs, states that `knots` argument is *internal* knots. scipy's `BSpline` does not pad the knots automatically, so you need to do it yourself. Using the OP data:

```
In [22]: women_height = np.array([58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72])
    ...: knots = np.array([59.4, 62.2, 65. , 67.8, 70.6])

In [23]: t = np.r_[(58,)*4, knots, (72,)*4]   # <<<<<< here

In [24]: m = BSpline.design_matrix(women_height, t, k=3)

In [25]: with np.printoptions(linewidth=120, precision=5):
    ...:     print(m.toarray())
    ...:
[[1.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [2.33236e-02 6.28442e-01 3.23939e-01 2.42954e-02 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 2.15581e-01 5.99895e-01 1.82884e-01 1.63994e-03 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 3.49854e-02 4.95627e-01 4.38290e-01 3.10982e-02 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 1.61970e-04 2.45586e-01 6.20809e-01 1.33443e-01 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 7.28863e-02 5.84548e-01 3.38678e-01 3.88727e-03 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 9.11079e-03 3.84718e-01 5.61893e-01 4.42784e-02 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 1.66667e-01 6.66667e-01 1.66667e-01 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 4.42784e-02 5.61893e-01 3.84718e-01 9.11079e-03 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 3.88727e-03 3.38678e-01 5.84548e-01 7.28863e-02 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 1.33443e-01 6.20809e-01 2.45586e-01 1.61970e-04 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 3.10982e-02 4.38290e-01 4.95627e-01 3.49854e-02 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 1.63994e-03 1.82884e-01 5.99895e-01 2.15581e-01 0.00000e+00]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 2.42954e-02 3.23939e-01 6.28442e-01 2.33236e-02]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 1.00000e+00]]
```

which looks similar to the R's output from the OP modulo the first column. From the R's docs it's not immediately clear how exactly it pads the knot vector, but if you want the same output, you can just chop the first column off (`m.toarray()[1:, :]` or some such).

Comment: How can I use that to reproduce the result above?

Comment: Plug in the knots you got from R

Comment: That gives a ValueError: `ValueError: Out of bounds w/ x = [58. 59. 60. 61. 62. 63. 64. 65. 66. 67. 68. 69. 70. 71. 72.].`

Comment: Like I said, can you add the knots from R to the question

Comment: Sure, done. If I do that, then I get a ValueError for `design_matrix_gh = BSpline(knots, np.eye(len(knots)-3-1), 3)(heights)`

Comment: I see. The immediate error is that the data is outside of the knot range (by construction). Try padding them with (data[0],) *3 and similar at the right-hand side of the interval.

Comment: One thing to note is that this stuff is new, so we can still tweak it before it's fixed by being released :-).

Comment: perfect, thanks! `t = np.hstack([58, 58, 58, 58, knots, 72, 72, 72, 72]);
pd.DataFrame(BSpline(t,  np.eye(len(t) - 3 - 1), 3)(heights)[:, 1:])` also works